# How can I change item or image color in tabBar swift?

Tags: xcode, swift

I want to change item color in `tabBar`, not text the items not selected etc Longtime aim searching about it, I didn't find. I just found this code, it does not change item or image color, just text. 
The default color is grey, I want to change it.

This is the code I found:

```
UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(redRGB: 93, greenRGB: 175, blueRGB: 228)
UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor .redColor()
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()], forState:.Normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try google for searching. No seriously try it.

For your problem. What is gray? UITabbaritems are standard grayed out in storyboard.

You can use

```
var image : UIImage? = UIImage(named:"myImage.png").imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
```

The option Always original keeps the image as it is and it will not be grayed out.

For problems with that => [Rendering always original problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34186287/uitabbar-displays-uitabbaritem-image-ignoring-rendering-mode-alwaysoriginal)

Comment: how i can change gray to red for sample ?

Comment: In your storyboard = > go to your UItabbar => change backgroundcolor

Comment: If you want to do tyhat programmatically you should make a UITabbarcontroller  and  implement your color change there

Comment: there is not color un tabbar view where i need to tap to change color ?

Comment: This should work => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30041127/ios-8-tab-bar-item-background-colour => make sure to implement classes and add the tabbarcontroller to your ui tabbar

Comment: wow thanks its fixed now i have problem in text color and font size :(

Comment: Do you use auto layout and size classes ? You can google your problem